# How to retrieve client devices (Printer, Scanner, Audio) in a client server environment

Tags: javascript, flash, silverlight, applet, activex

Is there any way to retrieve all devices connected to a client PC in a (JEE based) Client-Server environment? A client accesses a url with his web browser, which then detects all devices installed and connected to his client machine.

It can be achieved with a Java applet however there is no JRE installed, so this is not an option. Now I am looking for alternative ways - any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of an un-sandboxed client-side technology that could be used ? Flash, Silverlight, VB ?

Comment: You ask for applet alternatives? Then use different tags: Flash Silverlight, VisualBasic, JavaScript, ActiveX